# apt broken (unmet dependencies) after trying to install mysql

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies, purge

#### Solved

This question has been asked many times and I have been trying all the solutions I found on askubuntu/stackoverflow/random forum since yesterday but nothing works.

I downloaded a mysql deb bundle from [the official website](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) and I followed [this official tutorial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installation-excerpt/5.7/en/linux-installation-debian.html) to install a mysql server but it ended up breaking my apt. Now, any command results in a variation of this message:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
> libmysqlclient21 : Depends: mysql-community-client-plugins (= 8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04) but it is not installable
> mysql-community-client : Depends: mysql-community-client-core (= 8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04) but it is not installable
> mysql-community-server : Depends: mysql-community-server-core (= 8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04) but it is not installable
> E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

And `apt --fix-broken install` outputs this:

> Correcting dependencies... failed.
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
> libmysqlclient21 : Depends: mysql-community-client-plugins (= 8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04) but it is not installable
> mysql-community-client : Depends: mysql-community-client-core (= 8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04) but it is not installable
> mysql-community-server : Depends: mysql-community-server-core (= 8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04) but it is not installable
> E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
> E: Unable to correct dependencies

I have tried a lot of commands (dpkg -r, purge, clean, autoremove, autoclean...) but to no avail.
Is there a radical way to save my apt without reinstalling Ubuntu?

Any help would be appreciated.

PS: I'm running Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Hello. You have not said what version of Ubuntu. Have you tried to install the missing modules? A Google search brings up this info. <https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/mysql-8.0-amd64/mysql-common_8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb.html>

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have just found out how to fix my problem: a simple "sudo apt-get -f install" worked out. Weird that I didn't try that solution before but at least my pain has ended !

Comment: This kind of problem is **expected behavior** when you try to bolt new upstream software onto a two-year-old release of Ubuntu. Users of 20.04 will find it easiest to use a release of mysql from around the same period. For compatibility with newer software, use a newer release of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have read a bit more. At the end of [the tutorial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installation-excerpt/5.7/en/linux-installation-debian.html), they state

> If you are being warned of unmet dependencies by dpkg, you can fix them using apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

And indeed it fixed my problem.

Comment: Hello. Important lesson here. Always read all the instruction be fore starting.